# Python isinstance returns false for types with the same ID

Tags: python, python-2.x, isinstance

I am having a strange issue with [this code in cpuset](https://github.com/epickrram/cpuset/blob/e486ccf4eb2bf48afa2a84e5adacb9266fc43a64/cpuset/commands/set.py#L401). For some reason `isinstance('/user', str)` is returning `False`. I added some logging like this:

```
    log.debug("repr(name): %s", repr(name))
    log.debug("type(name): %s", type(name))
    log.debug("name.__class__: %s", name.__class__)
    log.debug("id(name.__class__): %s", str(id(name.__class__)))
    log.debug("id(''.__class__): %s", str(id("".__class__)))
    log.debug("isinstance(name, str)?: %s", str(isinstance(name, str)))
```

Here is the result.

```
180820-14:28:55 set    DEBUG    repr(name): '/user'
180820-14:28:55 set    DEBUG    type(name): <type 'str'>
180820-14:28:55 set    DEBUG    name.__class__: <type 'str'>
180820-14:28:55 set    DEBUG    id(name.__class__): 94668708986528
180820-14:28:55 set    DEBUG    id(''.__class__): 94668708986528
180820-14:28:55 set    DEBUG    isinstance(name, str)?: False
```

Pretty WTF I'd say. What is going on here?

Comment: Please add your python version

Comment: What is the result of `name == '/user'`?

Comment: did `str` get re-assigned? What does `isinstance('', str)` give you?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `str` itself has been overridden by some other class.  Try printing out `str` to see what it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I think it is because they have:

```
from builtins import str
```

[Apparently](http://python-future.org/str_object.html) this is to get a Python 3 like string. But... it is pretty messed up.

```
>>> from builtins import str
>>> isinstance("foo", str)
False
```

I guess that's what you get if you refuse to move to Python 3.

Comment: `python-future` strikes again!  `newstr` is a sneaky little class

Comment: well, in Python 3 semantics, that isn't a `str`, that is a `bytes` object, so I guess it is "correct". Indeed, this seems like a poor bandage for the issue - stick with one of the languages.